# Why do I get a constant return instead of scope_identity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2014

I've used Entity Framework many times in the past, and called stored procedures that return `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` with no problems.

However, sometimes (as is currently the case), these stored procedures revert to returning `1` all the time (occasionally, `-1`). In these cases, I've refreshed the procedures and checked everything I can think of. I'm using hand-coded classes and manually assigning the return values from my EF calls. I've created output parameters previously to handle this problem, only to have it stop happening just as mysteriously as it started.

I've called stored procedures like this in several MVC projects and had no issues. This project is a class library, and I'm making my DB calls from the constructors of my classes, but neither of those sound like credible explanations to me.

Does anyone have recommendations or experience dealing with a situation like this?

Answer (score -1):

Are you using SQL Server? You may have run into [this bug](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2019779)

Comment: Are you sure? The bug is about SCOPE_IDENTITY returning incorrect results which is what the OP appears to be experiencing.

Comment: That bug isn't supposed to cause a result of -1, which the OP says he's also occasionally seeing. But I'll admit I was too hasty in saying it's not related at all. It may be a combination of that bug and another problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is happening on SQL 2014. I'll add the tag to clarify, though.